# Reach a child class to another child class

Tags: php, oop, child-process

How to do it ?

```
class A {
     public anyfunction() {};
     /* $B = new B(); */
     /* $C = new C(); */
     /* its defined there */
}

class B extends A {
     function __construct() {
        $this->C->func(); // <---- Showing Error Here
     }
}

class C extends A {
     public function func() {
        echo "Hi";
     }
}
```

I can use B::func(); but i want to use $this->C->func() style

Comment: Classes inherit from their parents... not their siblings

Comment: Do you even have a problem that needs solving at all? You just "want" something, but there's no reasoning about why. Also, it appears you're unclear about what OOP is and how it works in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the goal is here, but I was curious after reading the question and decided to experiment with it. An object can contain another object that extends its class.

```
class A {
    // You cannot just do $B = new B(); and $C = new C();.

    // You also cannot have a constructor like this:
    //   public function __construct() {
    //       $this->B = new B;
    //       $this->C = new C;
    //   }
    // because then your constructor becomes recursive and you get an error like:
    // Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!

    // So, you have to pass them as constructor arguments.

    public function __construct() {
        // Because an A can have a B, or a C, or both, or neither, the constructor
        // must be written more flexibly.
        foreach (func_get_args() as $obj) {
            $this->{get_class($obj)} = $obj;
        }
    }
}

class B extends A {
     public function __construct() {
        // Because you are calling the method from C in the constructor of B, you 
        // have to invoke the constructor of the parent class first so that your B will 
        // have a C to refer to.
        call_user_func_array('parent::__construct', func_get_args());
        if (property_exists($this, 'C'))
        // Now this works.
        $this->C->func(); // <---- echos 'Hi'
     }
}

class C extends A {
     public function func() {
        echo "Hi";
     }
}
```

Then you can construct a `B` like:

```
$B = new B(new C);
```

and it will say

> Hi

It's weird.